# How to add buttons to a main window in Qt?

Tags: qt, window, mainwindow

I'm new to qt programming so please don't mind if you find it a noob question. I've added a button to my main window but when I run the code the button is not displayed. Here's my code:

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtWidgets>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
{
QPushButton *train_button = new QPushButton(this);
train_button->setText(tr("something"));
train_button->move(600, 600);
train_button->show();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow  
{  
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();

private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: For the beggining it is better (from my point of view) to create application with QWidget as base class. QMainWindow provide a lot of extra functionality and you may learn it only when you will have some experience it Qt.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In main window you should use central widget . You have two choices :

**Set the button for central widget ( Not so good choice ) :**

```
QPushButton *train_button = new QPushButton(this);
train_button->setText(tr("something"));
setCentralWidget(train_button);
```

**Add a widget and add the button to that widget and set the widget for centralWidget :**

```
QWidget * wdg = new QWidget(this);
QPushButton *train_button = new QPushButton(wdg);
train_button->setText(tr("something"));
setCentralWidget(wdg);
```

And surely you can use Layouts for your centralWidget:

```
QWidget * wdg = new QWidget(this);
QVBoxLayout *vlay = new QVBoxLayout(wdg);
QPushButton *btn1 = new QPushButton("btn1");
vlay->addWidget(btn1);
QPushButton *btn2 = new QPushButton("btn2");
vlay->addWidget(btn2);
QPushButton *btn3 = new QPushButton("btn3");
vlay->addWidget(btn3);
wdg->setLayout(vlay);
setCentralWidget(wdg);
```

Comment: What if I want to add more buttons? Should I use the same widget or create a new widget for each buttons?

Comment: @user2595561 ~> No ! You just have one central widget! You should use Layouts. I'll update my answer very soon.